# Visual Studio Community Edition 2022, menu item is greyed \ not selectable?

Tags: git, command, prompt

Within Visual Studio Community Edition 2022, under the GIT menu, Open in Command Prompt choice is greyed out. How can I enable this?

I've tried to Uninstall \ Reinstall, searching msg boards for my issue but not have found this issue listed or resolved

Comment: Do you have git installed? Is it in your PATH? Do you need to tell Visual Studio where git is?

Comment: On my previous laptop, I just installed VS and it was there. 
I have it installed and it's listed in the path.   
\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\v

 Not sure what is meant by 'tell visual studio where git is' (besides the obviousness of the question)
Appreciate your help

Comment: There's a field called "git path" in vs code's settings. Maybe that's incorrect?